# Why is Microsoft Graph token flow suddenly requesting permission or consent for offline access/access your data anytime?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

The response type is `token id_token`
and the scope is `openid email profile User.Read Files.ReadWrite.All Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder Sites.Read.All Contacts.Read`

I have used to http://calebb.net/ to verify that the scope is correct but somehow when I login to the web application with a new user. The login ask for new permission and the **Access your data anytime** is listed in the required permissions. I can't find anything wrong with the application, few months ago it worked if I remember right.

"token" show version 1.0, "id_token" show version 2.0
I used the https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ portal to register the app.

```
Request/Auth:
client_id   **d2abdd-2363-4ff9-b597-77d41e0*****
nonce   636758137819125046.ZmQ3OTA2MGYtNjE1ZC00YjJiLTk0OTItMmE3MmUwN2VjN2ExZTEwYzMzYjUtMzM5ZS00ZDA1LTk2NGItYmE1ZTNmZjExZmY2
redirect_uri    http://localhost:50214/
response_mode   form_post
response_type   token+id_token
scope   openid+email+profile+User.Read+Files.ReadWrite.All+Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder+Sites.Read.All+Contacts.Read
state   OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=pfKy_eqtfN6mMb8xCkPVmgd1VTcFUuYBvTe5Qu7TXV3nY4y92AfdJPj2kkr***************R5Co8AxcuHV6gZXLhfr-IMQ8jwpl4uKoeJ-5Rr-5RFs4Aty_Q_7rHMJD8Ipvhyi2-T5K7c5zAGhbfaTAt_FAkCzuEfFMsCpRiU4SAFTouvbX5NvYrT_KMzivp62mTBaLXdvDAS2Vehhkz1fXxQ8
x-client-SKU    ID_NET
x-client-ver    1.0.40306.1554
```

Does the openid scope add offline scope by default?

Comment: There is no error, just ask for new permission for your new user login? And after you agree, the new user can log in?

Comment: @SunnySun-MSFT Yes everything is working. Nothing goes wrong but the customer get afraid why we require access your data anytime when it is not used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing to worry. This is a necessary experience for every new user, this step is to make the new user grant the application consent.

Azure AD prompts the user for consent and displays the required permissions it needs to function. The set of permissions that are displayed in the consent dialog match the ones selected in the Delegated permissions in the Azure portal. For the details, you could read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/consent-framework).

Comment: But the offline permission was not used in token flow before. The problem is the "Access your data anytime". Do you mean that Microsoft have changed so offline permission is always required?

Comment: The offline permission means you could read the user data even though the user not signed in. If you do not choose it, you can only get the user data when the user sign in.

Comment: but I am using token flow so I am not use the code flow where I get the refresh token. And I am getting to token when the user sign in. I don't see why offline permission is shown when it not used in the scope.

Comment: The Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) currently specifies offline_access, openid, profile, and email by default in authorization and token requests.  For the details, you could read [openid permissions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#openid-permissions).

Comment: So if I understand you right openid automatically add offline_access scope? How do I remove the default scope offline_access?

Comment: And as I know, you could not remove the offline-access not matter as admin or user for the default setting.

Comment: hmm okey, I found this article good. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is that v2.0 endpoint always will include offline_access scope because requesting permission on demand require a refresh token.